# How do you use trigger.io enhanceInput() with Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, trigger.io

I'm building a mobile app for Android and iOS using Trigger.io.  Unfortunately, on Android, the date and time text fields through the webview component do not use the native datepickers and timepickers.  Trigger.io has an API call that can allow you to use the native controls, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it work.

I've got it *mostly* working using an Angular.js directive, which I am not very familiar with.  Here is my code:

```
if (forge.is.android())
{
  app.directive("ngNative", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "?ngModel",
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {

        elm.on('blur', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
          });
        });

        ngModel.$render = function() {
          forge.logging.info("Render value: " + ngModel.$viewValue);
          elm.val(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        }; 

        ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());

        attrs.$observe('id', function(id) {
          forge.logging.info('Trying to enhance #' + id); 
          forge.ui.enhanceInput('#' + id);
        });
      }
    };
  });
}
```

The idea is with that code, I should just be able to tag a control with an ngNative attribute, and angular will call the forge.ui.enhanceInput API with the input's ID.

Anyways, this mostly works.  However, the $render function doesn't seem to be getting called, and I'm not sure why.  So, when the input control gets rendered, it does not populate with the model's data.  It does however, update the model's data when I type something in the field.

Has anybody solved this problem already using a directive or other means?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the example above it looks like the problem is related to Angular rather than the Trigger.io call to forge.ui.enhanceInput. Can you confirm  that the 'Trying to enhance #' log message appears each time. If it does not, and if it still does not if you remove the forge.ui.enhanceInput line, then the problem is definitely not in the forge API call and you would need to seek guidance from the Angular community as to why that branch of code isn't getting called when you expect it to be.